# How to refresh CrystalReportViewer in WPF - VB.NET?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, crystal-reports

Any Know how to refresh CrystalReportViwer in wpf - vb.net?
I have two CrystalReports, first is working great but on a second I need to click refresh button to show correct data in Crystalreport viewer.

I tried to Discard Saved Data When Loading Reports but didn't helped me.

Public Class Izvjesce

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    'dinamički učitati crystal report iz baze podataka
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument

    Dim CrTables As Tables
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
    ' za dodati labele na crystal report
    Dim txtID As String = lblIDBroj.Content
    Dim txtPoduzece As String = lblPoduzece.Content





    cryRpt.Load("C:\Users\Stjepan Juric\source\repos\Plata\Plata\CrystalReport1.rpt")



    With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = lblPath.Content.ToString()
        '.DatabaseName = ""
        '.UserID = ""
        'Password = "password"
    End With

    CrTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
    For Each CrTable In CrTables
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
    Next

    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("TxtID", txtID)
    cryRpt.SetParameterValue("txtNaziv", txtPoduzece)
    cr1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cryRpt


End Sub



Private Sub Button_Click_1(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)


    'dinamički učitati crystal report iz baze podataka
    Dim rep2 As New ReportDocument

    Dim CrTables As Tables
    Dim crtableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo
    Dim crConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo
    ' za dodati labele na crystal report
    'Dim txtID As String = lblIDBroj.Content
    'Dim txtPoduzece As String = lblPoduzece.Content


    rep2.Load("C:\Users\Stjepan Juric\source\repos\Plata\Plata\CrystalReport2.rpt")



    With crConnectionInfo
        .ServerName = lblPath.Content.ToString()
        '.DatabaseName = ""
        '.UserID = ""
        'Password = "password"
    End With

    CrTables = rep2.Database.Tables
    For Each CrTable In CrTables
        crtableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
        crtableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = crConnectionInfo
        CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(crtableLogoninfo)
    Next

    'cryRpt.SetParameterValue("TxtID", txtID)
    'cryRpt.SetParameterValue("txtNaziv", txtPoduzece)

    cr1.ViewerCore.ReportSource = rep2



End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

I found what is problem.
Just add rep2.refresh to resolve it.

```
rep2.Load("C:\Users\Stjepan Juric\source\repos\Plata\Plata\CrystalReport2.rpt")
rep2.Refresh()
```